# Confirm if SSL on IIS can secure some pages and not others?

Tags: iis, ssl

I've worked primarily with Apache and with it i can secure some pages and not others on the same domain.  So I can simulatenously have the urls http://mysite.com/help.php and https://mysite.com/help.php.   A similar concept works on IIS with asp pages too right?  I can have both http://mysite.com/help.asp and https://mysite.com/help.asp ?

Just want to confirm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, sure. You can bind the website to both the HTTP (port 80) and HTTPS (port 443) protocol and have your site accessible with both protocols. Your application can decide when to switch between the two.

The only thing to remember though is that the use of host headers (multiple websites using the same IP address) is not yet possible with HTTPS in IIS 7.5 (and below), unless you have a multi-domain SSL certificate for all domains sharing the same IP address. This will be possible as of IIS 8.0 in Windows Server 2012.